# Symfony 1.4 Ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony1

I want to make a form on ajax in Symfony Framework. The problem is the only way I found is with jquery and .load function. But with this way how to pass post values? I don't want hardcode anything so be flexible, but how make ajax submission form in symfony 1.4 with post data? How pass input posts in the load function?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can go for "sfJqueryReloadedPlugin" plugin
http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfjqueryreloadedplugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.load is fine. You can grab the values of the form with jquery.

http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2009/05/04/how-to-use-jquery-to-serialize-ajax-forms/

The only issue is that you will have to bind the form manually yourself(in the controller). I consider that the bigger issue :P